Red background for specific word in VBA
I made a program that sends, through Outlook mail, inputs from a .csv file type:
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Setare culori dark mode
    Me.BackColor = RGB(48, 48, 48) ' culoare fundal
    Me.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' culoare text

    ' Personalizare pentru alte elemente
    ' Exemplu:
    ' Me.CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(64, 64, 64)
    ' Me.CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ' Me.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(64, 64, 64)
    ' Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub


Public Sub Email_Sheets_As_Table()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim csvFilePath As String
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim clientName As String
    Dim tableHTML As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim fileContent As String
    
    ' Client name
    clientName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    
    ' Specifica unde se afla raportul
    csvFilePath = "C:\RAPORT TEST\raport_test.csv"
    
    ' Citeste datele din raport
    Open csvFilePath For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, fileLine
        fileContent = fileContent & fileLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close #1
    Debug.Print "File Content:" ' Afiseaza un mesaj în fereastra "Immediate" pentru a identifica continutul (debug)
    Debug.Print fileContent ' Afiseaza continutul citit din fisier în fereastra "Immediate" (debug)

    ' exctracteaza datele din raport
    Dim csvLines() As String
    csvLines = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)
    Dim headers() As String
    headers = Split(csvLines(0), ",")
    Debug.Print "Column Headers:" ' Afiseaza un mesaj în fereastra "Immediate" pentru a identifica continutul (debug)
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        Debug.Print headers(i) ' Afiseaza fiecare eticheta de coloana în fereastra "Immediate" (debug / CTRL + G )
    Next i

    ' Creeaza tabelul
    tableHTML = "<html><body><p>Ceau,<BR> Raportul pentru schimb, atasat mai jos.</p>"
    tableHTML = tableHTML & "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>"

    ' Pune label-urile
    tableHTML = tableHTML & "<tr>"
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        tableHTML = tableHTML & "<th>" & headers(i) & "</th>"
    Next i
    tableHTML = tableHTML & "</tr>"

' HERE CREATES THE TABLE AND AS FAR AS I KNOW  BELOW SHOULD I PUT THE CODE FOR RED BACKGROUND

    ' Adauga datele din CSV in tabel
For i = 1 To UBound(csvLines)
    tableHTML = tableHTML & "<tr>"
    
    Dim csvLine As String
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim inQuotes As Boolean
    Dim character As String
    Dim cellContent As String
    
    csvLine = csvLines(i)
    cellContent = ""
    inQuotes = False
    
    For j = 1 To Len(csvLine)
        character = Mid(csvLine, j, 1)
        
        ' Verificam daca suntem într-un câmp citat
        If character = """" Then
            inQuotes = Not inQuotes ' Schimbam starea de citare
        End If
        
        ' Daca întâlnim virgula ?i nu suntem într-un câmp citat, consideram ca am terminat o valoare
        If character = "," And Not inQuotes Then
            ' Adaugam valoarea la tabel
            tableHTML = tableHTML & "<td>" & cellContent & "</td>"
            cellContent = "" ' Resetam con?inutul celulei pentru urmatoarea valoare
        ElseIf j = Len(csvLine) Then
            ' Daca suntem la sfâr?itul liniei, adaugam ultima valoare la tabel
            cellContent = cellContent & character
            tableHTML = tableHTML & "<td>" & cellContent & "</td>"
        Else
            ' Altfel, adaugam caracterul la con?inutul celulei
            cellContent = cellContent & character
        End If
    Next j
    
    tableHTML = tableHTML & "</tr>"
Next i

    ' Inchide tabelul
    tableHTML = tableHTML & "</table></body></html>"
    Debug.Print "HTML Table:" ' Afiseaza un mesaj în fereastra "Immediate" pentru a identifica continutul (Debug)
    Debug.Print tableHTML ' Afiseaza tabela HTML în fereastra "Immediate" (debug)

    ' Trimitere mail
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "y"
        .Cc = "x"
        .Subject = "Raport schimb " & clientName
        .HTMLBody = tableHTML
        .Display ' Afiseaza continutul inainte de a trimite mail-ul
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    ' Sterge csv ul
    Kill csvFilePath

    MsgBox "Deschideti Outlook pentru a se trimite raportul!"
End Sub

I want to make a specific column and specific input, with red background.
The specific column and line is named "BREAKDOWN" and it is on line 9 and column 0.
The input that must have red background is "DA" and it starts below it, line 9 and column 1 and so on. (It can be "DA" or "NU" so it isn't always the same.)
If I have red background for "BREAKDOWN" and "DA" but the column are not good (it creates a new line every time a new  ,  is there). But if I have the part where the lines are good, I can't have the red background.

Where appropriate replace the <td> with <td bgcolor="#FF0000"> (deprecated) or <td style="background-color:red;">.

Now it just made my whole table red ( except last line )
I guess it made everything red till "BREAKDOWN"
i'll try to figure

By "where appropriate" I meant you need some logic around the values of i , j and cellContent to determine whether to add the colour into the tag or not.
